# iPhone - Chinese and Japanese in UITextField

Tags: iphone, unicode, internationalization, uitextfield, cjk

I want to make sure some code I've written works well with Chinese and Japanese characters. I tried changing the iPhone Simulator language to Chinese and Japanese, but it doesn't look like the character set for the UITextFields change. How do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same (or similar) issue (chinese/japanese keyboards do not appear for `UITextField` even though they are enabled in settings whilst others, such as french, do appear).

Eventually I discovered that I had set the `KeyboardType` property to `UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet`. Commenting out this line caused the non-latin keyboards to show as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > International > Keyboards to enable the Japanese keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, but the keyboard on screen is still the basic qwerty one, even though I press that globe button. The only thing changing is the name of the space button.

Comment: Yes, and when you type it produces Japanese text.  There's also a non-qwerty Japanese keyboard available.

Comment: Still not working. Tried it on my iPod touch and it worked there, but not in the simulator.